# How can i fix Warning: Division by zero in OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

I have add below code for percentage discount badge(It automatically calculates the percentage between the old and new price.) for product. So, It is working fine.

**But When, add 0.00 price in product. so. get error.
Warning: Division by zero in /home/......**

So, any solution for this error. How can i fix it?

below code add in .php file

```
'saving'    => round((($product_info['price'] - $product_info['special'])/$product_info['price'])*100, 0)
```

below code add in .tpl file

```
<span class="saving">-<?php echo $product['saving']; ?>%</span>
```

Thanks.

Comment: if price is 0, can we say 100% discount ? zero - any non-zero value will give a negative number, so better add a `if` condition and display 100% discount or free.

Comment: You need to check that price is greater than zero before trying to divide by it.

Comment: @SankarV when add price is 0 in product from admin side. so, discount create 0% & also, create error Warning: Division by zero in /home/......

Comment: And in addition you shouldn't display products that have price = 0 otherwise if someone buys it you'll have a problem

Comment: @i-CONICA if I add price is greater than zero. so it is working fine. & also, have not get any error there.

Comment: let the `$product_info['price'] = 0` and `$product_info['special'] = 7.00` . what do you want to show as `saving`? can't we use a `if` condition ? - Please answer both questions.

Comment: @SankarV if i add $product_info['price'] = 0  So, get error Warning: Division by zero in /home/... & also, all product percentage is 100%. & also, use $product_info['special'] = 7.00 so, not display correct percentage.

Comment: Please read my questions carefully and answer both questions. I asked you what do you need to show as saving with `price = 0` and `special = 0`. Can't we use a `if` condition ?

Comment: if only i add price is 0 So, it will get error. even I have not mention special price. though & also, I am designer. so please can you let me know. any possibility there add condition. when price is 0. so not get error. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the message explains: Do not divide through zero. Your Price is zero.

**Option 1: Write a Function**

```
$array = [
'foo' => 'bar',
'donald' => 'duck',
'saving' => GetDiscount($product_info['price'], $product_info['special'])
]

//Get the Discount. If the Price is zero, Discount is 100 %
function GetDiscount($price, $special) {
    return $price === 0 ? 100 : round((($price - $special)/$price)*100, 0);
}
```

**Option 2: One Line**

```
$array = [
'foo' => 'bar',
'donald' => 'duck',
'saving' => $product_info['price'] === 0 ? 100 : round((($product_info['price'] - $product_info['special'])/$product_info['price'])*100, 0)
]
```

Comment: if, i use this code so, get error= Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\..........

Comment: Yeah, you not need an `;` at the end. Edited this.

Comment: Now get this error= Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in C:

Comment: Updated Answer to clarify. Have not tested the code ;)

Comment: It is work now. but, still Warning: Division by zero in /home/.... when product price is 0.

Comment: Then it is not `int` 0. try `==` instead of `===` in the condition. 3 times is for additional typecheck.